# Function randint() does not return an integer

Tags: python, random, int, sage

I faced a curious problem while taking the writing of an integer in bits in Python (I am working in Sage)

I first tried to run the code

```
m=7
m.bits()
```

Everything worked fine there. Then, I wanted to do this with a random integer. Thus, I tried to run the code

```
import random
m=randint(2,10)
m.bits()
```

That is where I got the error "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'bits'" as if the function randint was not returning an integer. I managed to force it to be an integer by doing

```
m=m+0
```

However, I am still wondering why the first writing was not working. I have to say that I am coding on online sage, even if I do not think this should be an issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Plain Python integers don't have a `.bits` method, but Sage Integers do: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_standard/sage/rings/integer.html#sage.rings.integer.Integer.bits

Comment: @vaultah I tried it in Sage and it did work. Maybe they have implemented such a method in Sage

Comment: The result of randint() is an int: `from random import randint; type(randint(2,10))` -> `<class 'int'>`

Comment: I don't now what Sage is , but can you explain what .bits() do, maybe there is a phytonic function for that

Comment: OTOH, you can use the builtin `bin` function in standard Python to get the binary representation of an in int as a string, eg `bin(13), which prepends `'0b'` to the bit string. Another option to do that is to use the format function or the `.format` method of `str`. Eg, `format(13, 'b')` or `'{0:b}'.format(13)`, neither of which prepends `'0b'`.

Comment: @PM2Ring `'{0:b}'.format(13)`

Comment: @Arman 8.bits() returns an array of length 4 where all entries are equal to 0 except the last one which is a 1. It's the writing of that integers in binary.
(Sage is a program that let you code with complex mathematical objects (e.g. finite fields, elliptic curves))

Comment: So try `bin` function , it represent binary of an integer instead `bits`

Comment: And in Python 3.6+ you can use an f-string, eg `n=13; f'{n:b}'`

Comment: @PM2Ring Well, I did found a solution by doing m=m+0, I was just wondering why I had to do that to avoid that error. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: Presumably `m = m + 0` converts an ordinary Python `int` object into a Sage `int` object. If you are running this in Sage, `0` must be interpreted as a Sage int and `+` as the operator which (when fed an int and a Sage int) returns a Sage int object.

Comment: @JohnColeman it certainly does, since most likely `__add__` between Sage integer and standard Python integer is implemented to return instance of former one. They just forgot to decorate `random.randint` so it returns their integer.

Comment: Sage didn't necessarily "forget" to decorate, in this case the "Sage" version of `random` was to allow the seed to be consistently set but otherwise mimic the module completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a random Sage integer (using various distributions), use `ZZ.random_element` ([doc here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_standard/sage/rings/integer_ring.html#sage.rings.integer_ring.IntegerRing_class.random_element)).  Try [this example](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLVLBViIrSK0rMS8nPjU_NSc1NzSvRMNIxNNDk5UrUS8osKdbQBADe-wtE&lang=sage):

```
a = ZZ.random_element(2,10)
a.bits()
```

I've opened [Trac 22131](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/22131) to clarify this issue; one shouldn't have to do something quite this elaborate, there could be a `random_integer` function at the top level.  (There is a `random_prime`, for instance.)